# AutoMapper Relacionamento um para muitos - Model to ViewModel (e vice-versa)

Tags: c#, relacionamento, automapper, viewmodel, model

Cenário MVC, onde Controller conversa com Application que conversa com Domain.

Estou tentando realizar um mapeamento de um para muitos com AutoMapper.

Este é meu Model:

```
public class Estado
{
    public Guid EstadoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public string Capital { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cidade> Cidades { get; set; }
}

public class Cidade
{
    public Guid CidadeId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Guid EstadoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
}
```

Assim está minha ViewModel: (parecem idênticas ao Model, mas não são. Para simplificar, eu omiti os DataAnnotations e os Métodos, pois não são relevantes à solução do problema)

```
public class EstadoViewModel
{
    public Guid EstadoId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public string Capital { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CidadeViewModel> Cidades { get; set; }
}

public class CidadeViewModel
{
    public Guid CidadeId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Guid EstadoId { get; set; }
    public virtual EstadoViewModel Estado { get; set; }
}
```

Na Application na classe "Model To ViewModel" eu tentei criar o mapeamento assim:

```
CreateMap<Cidade, CidadeViewModel>()
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Estado, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Estado));
```

No método ObterCidadePorId, estou tentando retornar um CidadeViewModel:

```
return Mapper.Map<Cidade, CidadeViewModel>(CidadeRetornadaDoModel);
```

Onde CidadeRetornadaDoModel representa uma Cidade e todos os dados do Estado relacionado, conforme consulta:

```
    SELECT C.CidadeId, C.Nome, C.EstadoId, E.Nome, E.Sigla
      FROM Cidades AS C
INNER JOIN Estados AS E
        ON C.EstadoId = E.EstadoId
     WHERE C.CidadeId = 1
```

Problema: a propriedade Estado em CidadeViewModel está retornando null. Acredito que o erro esteja no mapeamento (CreateMap) na classe "Model To ViewModel", mas não consigo resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola,
Vamos ver se consigo lhe ajudar. È possivel que você esteja utilizando a arquitetura DDD...
Levando em consideração que você tenha um conhecimento médio do EF vamos as possíveis soluções...

1. "*Problema: a propriedade Estado em CidadeViewModel está
   retornando null. Acredito que o erro esteja no mapeamento
   (CreateMap) na classe "Model To ViewModel", mas não consigo resolver
   o problema*"

   - Verificar se a tabela esta corretamente mapeada.
   - Verificar se o lazyload esta habilitado (Caso contrario, Não esquecer de
     chamar o metodo Include no EF).
2. AutoMapper

   - Percebe-se que sua modelagem possui uma recursividade que não é tratada pelo AutoMapper, por exemplo: sua classe [Estado] possui uma coleção [Cidades] , já sua classe [Cidade] possui um tipo [Estado] Isso causa uma recursividade tratada pelo EF, mas que não descobri como resolver isso no AutoMapper. Isso normalmente causa um overflow e o processamento aborta através de uma exceção. Assim, é  aconselhavel rever sua modelagem para que a recursividade não ocorra.

Espero ter lhe ajudado e caso encontre outra alternativa por favor deixe-me saber.